# include only pages with variable set appropriately

Tags: php

Is there a way to do this:

I have one main php file called "include.php" which contains:

```
<?php

if ($category = "salsa") {
    include '$pagename'.'php';
}

?>
```

and I want it only to include pages which have a variable set appropriately like the page e.g. "salsa.php" containing:

```
<?php

$category = "salsa";
$pagename = "salsa";

echo "hello world of salsa";

?>
```

and not the page "chachacha.php" containing:

```
<?php

$category = "chachacha";
$pagename = "chachacha";

echo "hello world of chachacha";

?>
```

I know it can't possibly be that easy but I'm just starting.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try it?  I'd try "include '$category.php';" if $category is going to be the same as the include file name + ".php"

Comment: I think it's even easier, you could just do `include $category . ".php";`

Answer (score 1):

`include '$pagename'.'php';` will fail. If you want to use the value, don't use quotes or use double quotes.
ALSO :: the point is for concatenation of the 2 strings, you need a 2nd one to define the file name.

`include $pagename.".php"`

Yes, it is that simple, but be sure to include `salsa.php` before the `include.php` (vars need to be defined before)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do.  But this may help:

Your include will not work with single quotes:

```
include '$pagename'.'php';
```

This will work:

```
include "$pagename.php";
```

And the include should many times  be followed with an `exit;`

### HTML

```
<form action="include.php" method='post"><div>
<input type="hidden" name="category"  value="foods" />
<button type="submit" name="pagename" value="chachacha">chachacha</button>
<button type="submit" name="pagename" value="salsa">Salsa</button>
</div></form>
```

### PHP

```
$filename = '/home/user/public_html/' . trim($_POST['pagename']) . '.php';
if(file_exists($filename)){
  include($filename);
}
else{
  include '/home/user/public_html/index.html'
}
exit;
```

or using the hidden input also could be something like:

```
$filename = '/home/user/public_html/' . trim($_POST['category']) . '/' . trim($_POST['pagename'] . '.php') ;
```

This is similar to how I recently did an index.php page:

Where every nave button is a form with a hidden input with the name sub and an integer value.

```
$sub = intval($_POST['sub']);

if($sub == 7){include('/home/user/public_html/home.php');exit;}
elseif($sub == 14){include('/home/user/public_html/page0.php');exit;}
elseif($sub == 21){include('/home/user/public_html/page1.php');exit;}
elseif($sub == 28){include('/home/user/public_html/page2.php');exit;}
elseif($sub == 35){include('/home/user/public_html/page3.php');exit;}
else{include('/home/user/public_html/index.html'}
```